# Servlet not working :HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, html, xml, servlets, java-ee-6

I developed a small web app using tomcat 7 and javac compiler, i compiled my servlet successfuly and deployed the class file correctly. My html form runs however when i click the submit button on the html it is suppose to run the servlet which then print some advice on the page but this error is produced:

HTTP Status 404 - HTTP Status 404 - /beer-v1/%E2%80%9DSelectBeer.do%E2%80%9D

---

type Status report

message /beer-v1/%E2%80%9DSelectBeer.do%E2%80%9D

description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.34

---

type Status report

message /beer-v1/SelectBeer.do

description The requested resource is not available.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.34

Here is my html code:

```
    <h1 align=”center”>Beer Selection Page</h1>

    <form method=”POST”

          action=”SelectBeer.do”>

        Select beer characteristics<p>

            Color:

            <select name=”color” size=”1”>

                <option value=”light”> light </option>

                <option value=”amber”> amber </option>

                <option value=”brown”> brown </option>

                <option value=”dark”> dark </option>

            </select>

            <br><br>

        <center>

            <input type="submit" value="ok" />

        </center>

    </form></body></html>
```

and my deployment descriptor:

```
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

last my servlet:

```
package com.example.web;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,

        HttpServletResponse response)

        throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>");

    String c = request.getParameter("color");

    out.println("<br>Got beer color " + c);
 }
}
```

im using Java 6 javac compiler
Help me out please.

Comment: what is the name of your war file that you deployed? From the error message looks like servlet context path is `beer-v1`. Therefore, your war file should be `beer-v1.war` or you will have to set proper context path in Tomcat.

Comment: i did not package my app in a war file i just deployed the actual files to the tomcat server

Comment: in your web.xml can you try this `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>` and post back the result

Comment: You can also try this: in web.xml change `<url-pattern>` to `/SelectBeer` (without .do extension) and in html form set action to `SelectBeer`

Comment: What exactly did you do to deploy your files. You should be aware that the same thing would happen if the web.xml is not deployed at all for example.

Comment: i created a development environment on the desktop and deployment environment at CATALINA_HOME/webapps

Comment: and i deployed actual unpackaged files, no war

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to declare explicitly the appropiate charset on your html file, at head section.

```
<head><meta charset="utf-8"> <title>... </head>
```

%E2%80%9D represents hex notation of right double quotation character (using UTF-8). So, it seems that Tomcat is trying to convert ”SelectBeer.do”`to UTF-8 finding no encoding declaration.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

write action in form as below and test again

action=”/SelectBeer.do”

Comment: hi sujikin, Unfortunately it is not working

Comment: I tried to replicate exactly the same as your code in a new project in eclipse. It is working perfectly fine. It must be some very simple mistake.Is there any way you can share your project online?

Comment: sujikin, i am not supposed to use an IDE, im preparing for the OCE web component exam and they adviced us not to use IDEs for fast learning purposes

Comment: if you can share your code then I can comment further. With the code that you have provided here, I can compile and run without any issues.